# Nested Classes in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, class, nested

I am trying to create a nested class to perform sum or multiplication of the arguments passed in each subclass.
The below example helps me perform action within the class, however I am unable to find any documentation which would help me with inheriting the attributes from the Parent Class to child.

Recently I came across an article which highlights "**nested classes can't access any members of their outer classes at compile-time.**". Is there a better way to pass the values between Classes? I tried using global variables, but would like to avoid setting many global variables while I scale this logic to extract my entire datacenter's inventory, perform some calculations and again pass to another class.

```
class Class1:
    firstnumber=0
    def __init__(self,arg):
        self.firstnumber=arg

    class Class2:
        def __init__(self,arg):
            self.secondnumber=arg

        def sumit(self):
            return Class1.firstnumber+Class1.Class2.secondnumber


print(Class1(5).firstnumber)
print(Class1(6).Class2(4).secondnumber)

print(Class1(4).Class2(10).sumit())
```

I would like to perform calculations with 
Class1(variable1).Class2(variable2).Class3(variable3).sum() or
Class1(variable1).Class2(variable2).Class3(variable3).multiple() and eventually be able to do following

Datacenter('DC1').GetServer('ServerName').GetStorageCapacity('NFS').Used()
Datacenter('DC1').GetServer('ServerName').GetStorageCapacity('NFS').Free()

http://momentaryfascinations.com/programming/bound.inner.classes.for.python.html

Comment: Looks like a misunderstanding on your part. The documentation you cite is correct. The problem you are trying to solve does not really require nested classes.

Comment: Thanks for constructive feedback.

Answer (score -2):

i may be wrong but to my understanding anything you put in between the class() and the **init** statement is permanent and unchangable. you shouldn't need to create seperate classes for each number. create different instances of the same class.

```
class numbers:
    def __init__(self,arg):
        self.arg = arg
```

c1 = numbers(3)
c2 = numbers(5)

i don't know how you would add the arg variables together maybe someone else can fill in what i'm missing.

Comment: I chose the number example to make it generic. We have datacenters across the globe in different cities. I want to retrieve the data from different tools used across these datacenters. If someone helps me with nested classes it can help me with query and retrieve the server, storage and other details of these severs using the following Datacenter('DC1').GetServer('ServerName').GetStorageCapacity('NFS').Used()